# ruby and references. Working with fixnums

Tags: ruby, pass-by-reference, fixnum

I know a bit about ruby way to handle objects and references. The replace stuff, ect ...

I know it d'ont work on fixnum, cause the var is the fixnum. But i wish to change the value of a fixnum inside a function, and that the value changed in the ouside var.

How can i do this ?

I guess i can use a string like this "1" but that's quite dirty.

Comment: Please provide code for what you are trying to do.  Your question is confusing.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Generic way to replace an object in it's own method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9130994/generic-way-to-replace-an-object-in-its-own-method)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could pass an array with a single number, like `[1]`, or a hash like `{value: 1}`. Less ugly than a string, as your number itself remains a number, but less overhead than a new class...

Comment: But Arrays are objects, how can there be less overhead for creating an Array than just a bare object? Is there some crazy optimization for Arrays in ruby implementations?

Comment: I meant implementation overhead, not execution overhead. And I was comparing these with creating a new class, like in Semyon's answer. Also, in Ruby we call {}s hashes, not objects...

Answer (score 5):

Ruby will always pass-by-reference (because everything is an object) but Fixnum lacks any methods that allow you to mutate the value. See "[void foo(int &x) -> Ruby? Passing integers by reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2650634/void-fooint-x-ruby-passing-integers-by-reference)" for more details.

You can either return a value that you then assign to your variable, like so:

```
a = 5
def do_something(value)
    return 1 #this could be more complicated and depend on the value passed in
end
a = do_something(a)
```

or you could wrap your value in an object such as a Hash and have it updated that way.

```
a = {:value => 5}
def do_something(dict)
  dict[:value] = 1
end
do_something(a) #now a[:value] is 1 outside the function
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Not quite. Everything is an object and it is always pass by value but the value is always a reference. The problem is that there are no mutating methods for Fixnum so you can't change the value of a Fixnum.  You can change a String that is passed to a method though: `def pancakes(str) str << ' pancakes' end` and then `s = 'have some';pancakes(s); puts s` for example. The solutions make sense though.

Comment: AH, right, thanks. It's too easy to treat immutable objects as though they are just simple values.

Comment: @tjarratt: That's because when they are immutable it is impossible to distinguish whether the value was passed directly or a reference to the value was passed. You can only observe the difference when the object is mutated outside of the method, but immutable objects can't be mutated.

Comment: Thanks for the idea. I will use an array.

Comment: i really wish this answer said pass reference by value, to avoid confusion

Answer (score 2):

When I was building a game I had the same problem you have. There was a numeric score that represented how many zombies you've killed and I needed to manually keep it in sync between Player (that incremented the score), ScoreBar and ScoreScreen (that displayed the score). The solution I've found was creating a separate class for the score that will wrap the value and mutate it:

```
class Score
  def initialize(value = 0)
    @value = value
  end

  def increment
    @value += 1
  end

  def to_i
    @value
  end

  def to_s
    @value.to_s
  end
end
```

Comment: It probably would be a good idea to use `SimpleDelegator`. See my answer to this similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9130994/generic-way-to-replace-an-object-in-its-own-method

Comment: In this simple case I'd prefer explicitly exposing the methods I need. But using Simple Delegator might be a good choice if you need an object to have all numeric methods.