# How to "replace" number objects in-place in Ruby

Tags: ruby, pass-by-reference

I'm attempting to adjust a variable inside a Ruby/Rails function.  Standard stuff for many other languages.

In c:

```
void change(int *io){
  *io = 1;
}
```

Now we all know that Ruby is pass by reference (*smiley face*). This bit of code works perfectly:

```
def tester()
  value = 'dave'
  test_replace(value)
  p value.to_s;
end

def test_replace(ioValue)
  ioValue.replace 'test'  
end
```

The output is 'test'.

So the problem is: fixed numbers don't have a replace method. They are not passed the same way as other values.

So my question is: how do I "io" an "int" in Ruby?

```
def tester()
  value = 10
  test_replace(value)
  p value.to_s;
end

def test_replace(ioValue)
  ioValue.replace 15  
end
```

Which raises

> undefined method `replace' for 10:Fixnum

Comment: Not really objects ??? They are what we call immutable.

Comment: Please don't comment on the example.. it's 100% contrived for the question.  Also the pass by value thing has been settled in other SO entries :)

Comment: why is this down voted?  I mean honestly.. pass by reference is a real thing?  Down votes just puzzle the snot out of me.

Comment: @daveatflow: I agree. These are bizarre downvotes. Well, +1.

Comment: There is no pass-by-reference in Ruby in the sense that you're talking about.  All method parameters are immutable local variables.  If they happen to point to an object, you can call methods on that object.  Those methods may modify the object, but they can't change which object the variable references.  In the case of fixnums, the underlying object itself is immutable and presents no public API for replacing it.

Comment: Here's a [relevant thread from ruby-talk](http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/679033) too.

Comment: @JimStewart did you say "happen to point to an object?"  First.. I think they always point to an object.   And second... that's what pass by reference means. If the word point is in the description then it's a reference... But I digress.

Comment: @daveatflow yes, objects are passed by reference.  The references are immutable values though, so if the referenced object doesn't have self-mutating methods you can't change it.

Comment: I wonder why fixnum didn't get a mutant power?   Seems altering a status variable would be handy... Error codes could also be handily.. As opposed to having a class/object variable.

Comment: @daveatflow: Performance. Because fixnums are immediate, and because there is only one fixnum object for every value. There is only one 2, only one 3, etc.

Comment: Embrace the wonders of immutable data structures! They’re good for you `:)`.

Comment: I would be incredibly surprised to see a reasonable use case for this.  I think it is more likely that you're still thinking in C.

Comment: Ruby is pass by value. Period.

Comment: possible duplicate of [void foo(int &x) -> Ruby? Passing integers by reference?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2650634/void-fooint-x-ruby-passing-integers-by-reference)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are really two ways to do this:

1. Wrap in an object
2. Wrap in an array
3. Create a mutable-int proxy object

Option two is easy, and I won't give an example. Option 1 would look like this:

```
class IntRef < BasicObject
  def initialize(i)
    @int = i
  end
  def replace(v)
    @int = v
  end
  def method_missing(name, *args, &block)
    @int.send(name, *args, &block)
  end
end
```

Or option three: A proxy object!

```
class MutableInt < BasicObject
  def initialize(i)
    @int = i
  end
  def method_missing(name, *args, &block)
    v = @int.send(name, *args, &block)
    if(v.is_a?(::Fixnum))
      @int = v
      return self
    end
    v
  end
end
```

**WARNING:** Anything, *anything* you do to this proxy sticks and changes the object. Beware.

Comment: That is nutz ugly.. But valid... Uggh  I hope others have a different way..  I didn't want to have to write code outside the function to support changing a value.  Especially since I'm using the value in several places..   Thanks :)

Comment: @daveatflow: Sorry, but this is the best way. There is no better way to do this.

Comment: @daveatflow: Actually, hold on for a moment. I have an idea... (diabolical laughter) :).

Comment: @daveatflow: The * in Ruby means something completely different than in C. Although 2 is the best option.

Comment: Yeah.. sorry that's what I meant.. It would just make my code easier to read if I kept it as close to my heart as I could

Answer (score 5):

@Linuxios is correct in his explanation about pass by value, but his work-arounds are pretty awkward.  It's very easy to box a fixnum with a [SimpleDelegator](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/delegate/rdoc/SimpleDelegator.html) that supports a replace:

```
class NumberBox < SimpleDelegator
  alias_method :replace, :__setobj__
  class <<self; alias_method :[], :new; end
end

def tester()
  value = NumberBox[10]
  test_replace(value)
  p value.to_s;
end

def test_replace(ioValue)
  ioValue.replace 15  
end
```

In the above `value` will behave exactly like the object it delegates to, established at initialization (with `::new` or the `NumberBox::[]`) except it also supports the `__setobj__` method and its alias `replace` which binds a new object as the delegatee.

Comment: Nice solution! I've never heard of SimpleDelegator before. +1!

Answer (score 0):

> Now we all know that Ruby is pass by reference

On the contrary, Ruby is pass by value only. No pass by reference. Same as Java, Python, etc.